# Can anyone sketch an outline of Iwaniec's proof for the upper bound regarding the Jacobsthal function?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

A proof by H. Iwaniec in *'On the problem of Jacobsthal, Demonstratio Math. 11, 225–231, (1978)'* shows that: $$j(N) \ll \log^2 (N)$$

where $j(N)$ is the [Jacobsthal function](http://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function).

I am very interested in understanding the details of this proof.

Would anyone be able to provide a rough outline of the proof and suggest a good reference for understanding the theory behind Iwaniec's argument?

---

Edit: I changed the expression based on feedback.  $\log \log N$ was incorrect so I am changing it to $\log^2(N)$

Comment: Would anyone be able to provide a link to that paper? I can't find it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I couldn't find it either.

Comment: No, not just anyone could do it.

Comment: Pintz (1997) showed that $j(N)>(2e^\gamma + o(1)) \log N \log\log N \log \log\log\log N/(\log\log\log N)^2$ i.o., so it can't be true that $j(N)\ll\log\log N.$

Comment: Hi Charles, I see references like [this](http://www.tcnj.edu/~hagedorn/papers/JacobPaper.pdf) all the time.  Just google Iwaniec Jacobsthal.  Are you sure your analysis is correct?

Comment: @LarryFreeman: Quite. The link you provided matches my information: $j(n)\ll\log^2n=(\log n)^2.$ (That paper uses the convention $\log_2n=\log\log n$ but $\log_2n\ne\log^2n.$)

Comment: If you prefer numerics, note that j(76964283982898776138308824190) = 236 which is much closer to $2e^\gamma\log N\approx237$ but $\log\log N\approx4.2.$ (See  Hajdu & Saradha 2012 for this calculation.)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but doesn't $\log \log (N) = \log^2 n$?  Why would $\log \log n = \log_2 n$?  I'm refering to 0.1 in the paper to be clear.

Comment: @LarryFreeman: It's just notation. $\log^2n=(\log n)^2,$ just like $\sin^2x=(\sin x)^2.$ (It's not being composed twice.) Similarly, this author uses $\log_kx$ to refer to the $k$-fold iterated logarithm, not the base-$k$ logarithm, as you can see in the formula just above (0.1). That's also fairly standard notation, though unfortunately in conflict with the high-school standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Iwaniec shows in that paper is that
$$
j(N)\ll\omega(N)^2\log^2\omega(N)
$$
where $\omega(N)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $N$. As a result, if $N$ is less than $2\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot p_{n+1}$ then $j(N)\ll n^2\log^2n.$

By the Prime Number Theorem, that product is $e^{(1+o(1))p_{n+1}}=e^{(1+o(1))n\log n}$ and the square of the logarithm of that quantity is asymptotic to $n
^2\log^2n$ which is just the quantity of Iwaniec.

The method of proof is the Iwaniec's shifted sieve, an improvement to the [linear sieve](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/linear-sieve/) ("inspired by the work of Halberstam and Richert", i.e., [Mean value theorems for a class of arithmetic functions](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa18/aa18125.pdf)). I'm not familiar enough with sieve theory to give details.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I've updated my question based on your comment.

Comment: I'm not unfamiliar with the notation.  I guess that I had made a mistake specifically to $\log^2 n$.  I appreciate being corrected and your answer.  Please state your answer in the form that you feel is most clear.  :-). Cheers.

Comment: @LarryFreeman: Not trying to accuse -- just trying to be clear. :) $\log\log n$ is always unambiguous, but $\log_2n$ can mean either that or $\log n/\log2.$ $f^m(n)$ can mean $f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f(n)$ or $(f(n))^m$, but I've never seen $\log^m$ (or, for that matter, $\sin^m$) used to mean repeated composition.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right.  I did a search and I can't find any example of $\log^2 m = \log \log m$. As far as my original question, I did find an interesting [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.1064.pdf) on Arxiv.org.  Talks about the proof behind an explicit upper bound for the Jacobsthal function.  I don't know if you have already seen it.

Comment: @LarryFreeman: I hadn't, no -- thanks!