# Riemann sum with reduced residue system modulo $n$

Tags: number-theory, analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-sum

How to prove this conjecture？

> **Conjecture**  $f$ is Riemann integrable function in$[0,1]$,then
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\varphi(n)}\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\(k,n)=1}}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x
> $$

similar to Weyl's criteria？

Comment: By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Partitions_of_an_interval)? You have to show that the partitions induced by taking relatively prime $k$ have subintervals of lengths tending uniformly to $0$ when $n\to\infty$. This should be true since for large $n$ ["almost all" $k$ are relatively prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate) to it.

Comment: @Conifold I don't think we can solve it by this way,is there information about the ditribution of number coprime with $n$?I can't find the regularity of it.

Comment: prove this first for the exponentials $e^{2\pi i m}, m \ne 0$ where LHS is a Ramanujan sum and there are known estimates that imply that LHS $ \to 0$ while the RKS integral is obviously zero; then for continuous periodic functions one uses standard approximation theory (eg Feijer sums) and then for general continuous functions, they became periodic with one possible jump discontinuity and the argument above extends and then it extends to step functions, hence to Riemann integrable functions

Comment: See the [Jacobsthal function $g(n)$](http://oeis.org/A048669), which gives the maximal gap between integers relatively prime to $n$, and upper bounds for it. In particular, Iwaniec proved that $g(n)\ll\log^2(n)$, the proof is discussed under [Can anyone sketch an outline of Iwaniec's proof for the upper bound regarding the Jacobsthal function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/568856/152568)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method gives a proof with the assumption that $f(x)$ is of bounded variation in $[0,1]$. It is possible to generalize this to loose conditions.

For convenience, we define:

\begin{aligned}
S(x)
&=\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le x\\(k,n)=1}}1=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac xd\right\rfloor \\
&={\varphi(n)\over n}x+\mathcal O(2^{\omega(n)})
\end{aligned}

This implies that

$$
Q(x)=\sum_{1\le k\le x}\left[S(n)-S(n-1)-{\varphi(n)\over n}\right]\ll2^{\omega(n)}
$$

then we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\(k,n)=1}}f\left(\frac kn\right)
&={\varphi(n)\over n}\sum_{1\le k\le n}f\left(\frac kn\right)+\sum_{1\le k\le n}f\left(\frac kn\right)[Q(k)-Q(k-1)] \\
\end{aligned}

Certainly, the first sum will converge to $\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx$ as $n\to\infty$ when its divided by $\varphi(n)$, so the remaining task is to bound the second sum. By summation by parts, we have

\begin{aligned}
E
&=\sum_{1\le k\le n}f\left(\frac kn\right)[Q(k)-Q(k-1)] \\
&=\sum_{1\le k\le n}f\left(\frac kn\right)Q(k)-\sum_{0\le k\le n-1}f\left(k+1\over n\right)Q(k) \\
&=f(1)Q(n)-f(0)Q(0)-\sum_{0\le k\le n-1}Q(k)\left[f\left(k+1\over n\right)-f\left(\frac kn\right)\right] \\
\end{aligned}

Since bounded variation is assumed, we have

$$
E\ll2^{\omega(n)}[f(0)+f(1)]+2^{\omega(n)}\ll2^{\omega(n)}
$$

Consequently, we have

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over\varphi(n)}\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\(k,n)=1}}f\left(\frac kn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx+\lim_{n\to\infty}{\mathcal O(2^{\omega(n)})\over\varphi(n)}
$$

Using the property of divisor function, we know that $2^{\omega(n)}\ll\sigma_0(n)\ll_\varepsilon n^\varepsilon$, so the latter limit will certainly vanish.